# Java Canvas doesn't resize correctly

Tags: java, swing

I have to programm a game with the exact resolution of 128x128 but the Canvas dont want to match.

```
public class Window extends Canvas{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JFrame frame;

public Window(BufferedImage icon){
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(128, 128));
    this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(128, 128));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(128, 128));

    this.setSize(128, 128);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
    if(icon != null){
        frame.setIconImage(icon);
    }
}}
```

The size of the Canvas (getWidth(), getHeight) is 134*128 instad of 128*128..

Comment: What does `.pack()` do?

Comment: `JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` by default, not need to manually set it. Also, the `JFrame` used a `JPanel` as the content pane, and swing components tend to come with borders. To see if it has a border, check the values of `frame.getContentPane().getInsets()`. To get rid of the insets, simply call `frame.getContentPane().getInsets().set(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think getHeight would return the 134. That would. Be the title of the window. Is the Jframe obviously the bigger portion?

Comment: Its definetly the getWidth(), has nothing to do with the title.

Comment: There is no more related code this is all that manages the Frame and Canvas creation.

Comment: In that case, take out minsize, maxsize, & prefsize.

Comment: Use setLayout(new GridLayout(0,0));

Comment: setLayout(new GridLayout(0,0)); can just be called on the JFrame, and the values "0,0" give a error because you can not have 0 rows or cols - also "1,1" doesnt work

Comment: Use `FlowLayout` then. I just read that BorderLayout is a do-what-i-want method.

Comment: @DavidPulse `BorderLayout` is not "*do what I want*". It's "*do what I was created to do*"

Comment: Well they all are, but you don't use lacking interfaces to hone a final product. ICYMI This is doing whatever it wants. So now he has FlowLayout, and I'm assuming it worked because he left.

Comment: BorderLayout isn't lacking. It was created for a specific purpose. Seeing how he didn't mention what he was using the canvas for, how could you know `BorderLayout` is inefficient for this? It seems as if he wants 1 canvas to fill the whole screen, and `BorderLayout` would work just fine for that. Nothing in programming does "whatever it wants", so yes, I missed that part. There are a reasons behind the results you get. Suggesting things at random is never good. You should always find the source of the problem before attempting to fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977420/how-to-make-a-java-swing-jframe-resize-correctly?rq=1 this is where I got it9

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't call your class Window. There is an AWT component using that name so it is very confusing. Class names should be more descriptive.
2. Don't extend Canvas. When using Swing your would extend JComponent or JPanel for custom painting.
3. Don't create the frame in your class. The frame is not a property of the class and doesn't belong there.

> I have to programm a game with the exact resolution of 128x128

Works fine for me on Windows.

> Its definetly the getWidth(),

There is a minimum width of the frame. The frame must be able to paint all the buttons in the title bar and the left/right borders.

So I would guess that because you are using a BorderLayout, the frame is being resized to its minimum and then your custom class is resized based on the rules of the layout manager.

So if you want the preferred size of the panel to be respected, try a different layout manager on the frame. For example use a FlowLayout, it will respect the size of any component added to it.

Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GamePanel extends Canvas
{
    public GamePanel()
    {
        setBackground( Color.RED );
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(128, 128);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GamePanel");
        frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
        System.out.println(panel.getSize());
        System.out.println(frame.getSize());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `Don't extend Canvas` What if you are drawing without Swing components, such as creating a game or some kind of whiteboard application?

Comment: @VinceEmigh, you use a JComponent or JPanel for the custom painting.

Comment: But why not `Canvas` if you don't need component support? It doesn't make sense to use a container if you aren't adding to it. Seems like an overkill, are there any downfalls to using `Canvas`? Or it is just for consistency with `JFrame`?

Comment: @VinceEmigh,  `It doesn't make sense to use a container if you aren't adding to it.` - these are the components you use in Swing for doing custom painting. `Or it is just for consistency with JFrame` Yes, AWT and Swing have different painting conventions. Canvas is an AWT component. It works better know than it did in the past but you can still have problems mixing heavyweight (AWT) and lightweight (Swing) components. So the general advice is don't if you don't need to.